# Cooling fan causes shutdown

Tags: gpio, power, shutdown

I'm using Raspberry Pi 3 with 5V/2.5A input.

I'm going to do heavy work with Rasp (so need to cool CPU). Today I bought 5 V mini fan for my Raspberry and plugged to GPIO pins 4 and 6. While typing on the terminal, operating system shuts down itself, but fan continues to work. Is it normal, do I need to power my fan externally and if so could I use any mobile charger?

What is your opinion?

Comment: You mean, pins 4 and 6 of the GPIO header?

Comment: what's the power requirements for the 5v fan? I think you would be limited to 200mA - including whatever you have in USB - read https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations for a break down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a problem for the power required by the fan. You can not draw power from GPIO. If you need the GPIO to pilot the fan (for example to start it when the temperature rises over a preset value) you must use a transistor (or something else) as a switch. Take power (for the transistor) directly from the main power supply of  Pi or from another external supply.

[here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/46598/how-to-operate-a-cooling-fan-using-gpio-pins-rasppi2?rq=1)  you have one example.

Comment: The best I can do is yours for now